# Use of "this" instead of "that"?

Tags: grammar

In a TV programme, the host asked a person about the literacy rate of his city. The person replied 96%. The host then looked at the camera and said, "Wow, can you believe that?"

My question is about the use of *that*; if he had used *this* instead of *that*, would it be wrong?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it would be wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

We use **that** to refer back to something someone said or did:

For e.g. : Shall, we go to cinema? Yes, that's a good idea!!

Here also, the host said " Wow, can you believe **that**?

because the sentence was not spoken by him but by someone else. So, determiner **that** is used.